# passing variables between classes in python

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
class VM():
    def __init__(self):
        global vmitems,vmappid
        vmitems = {'url' : 'stuff','vmid' : '10'}

    def create(self, **vmitems):
           appurl = vmitems.get('url')
           vmappid   = vmitems.get('vmid')
           vmitems.update(vmid=vmappid)
           vmitems.update(url=appurl)
           print 'New URL: '+appurl
           print 'New ID: '+vmappid
           print 'NEW LIST: ',vmitems
           return vmitems

    def delete(self, **vmitems):
           appurl = vmitems.get('url')
           vmappid   = vmitems.get('vmid')
           print 'do stuff'

action = VM()
action.create(url='https://www.google.com', vmid='20')
action.delete(url='urlhere',vmid='20')
print 'New List: ',vmitems
```

I was wondering if anyone can tell me how would I pass the value of `vmitems` around to other classes/functions

UPDATE: Corrected. Issue was not using self and not passing them around (sorry still learning and new to python).

```
    class VM():
        def __init__(self):
            self.vmitems = {'url' : 'stuff','vmid' : '10'}

        def create(self, **vmitems):
           print 'Original: ',self.vmitems
           appurl = vmitems.get('url')
           vmappid   = vmitems.get('vmid')
           self.vmitems.update(vmid=vmappid)
           self.vmitems.update(url=appurl)
           print 'New URL: '+appurl
           print 'New ID: '+vmappid
           print 'NEW LIST: ',vmitems
           return self.vmitems

        def delete(self):
           print 'Before Delete: ',self.vmitems
           self.vmitems.update(vmid='30')
           self.vmitems.update(url='newurl')
           return self.vmitems

        def shownow(self):
            print 'After Delete: ',self.vmitems
```

Comment: You aren't using a single instance variable here. I think you might be misunderstanding the purpose of classes.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm suggesting a different approach then you used in your code it will require some changes but i think it will be much easier to use.

If it's for methods inside you class just use `self`:

```
class VM():
    def __init__(self):
        self._vmitems = {'url' : 'stuff','vmid' : '10'}

    def some_func():
        print self._vmitems
```

if you want it to be available to other class i would use [@property](http://www.programiz.com/python-programming/property):

```
class VM():
    def __init__(self):
        self._vmitems = {'url' : 'stuff','vmid' : '10'}

    @property
    def get_vmitems(self):
        print("Getting vmitems")
        return self._vmitems
```

Comment: @Andrew i have multiple classes which rely on each other. 
as an example.

i Create a VM which has id,name
then storage which has its own ID/Name which is not related to VM
then network which has its own ID/Name which is not related to VM then attaching Storage/Network to VM (using ID)

so when i create the storage i can pass the ID value back to createVM process. i hope this make sense.


VM->Network